# Unable to implement dependent dropdowns

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, django-forms

I have been trying to implement dependent dropdowns in my forms but I have been unable to get it right, since I don't know much about jquery, but I think I'm doing something wrong. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it.
The problem is upon selecting the fl no field, park_bay does not get updated [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3TwN.jpg)

followed the post written by Vitor Freitas which can be found here [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

The models.py of app called postlog:

```
from django.db import models
class flight(models.Model):
    fl_no =models.CharField(max_length=6,primary_key=True)
    inbound= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    dest= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    park_bay= models.CharField(max_length=3)
    airline= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dep_time= models.TimeField()
    arr_time= models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fl_no
```

The table provided below is of another app.

The models.py of an app called status:

```
from django.db import models
from postlog.models import flight

# Create your models here.
class FlightStatus(models.Model):
    Yes = 1
    No = 2
    CLEANING_CHOICES = (
        (Yes, 'Yes'),
        (No,'No'),
    )
    fl_no= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fli_no')
    park_bay= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='parki_bay')
    catering= models.CharField(max_length=9)
    fuel= models.IntegerField()
    pas_cnt= models.IntegerField()
    dest= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='desti')
    dep_time=models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='dept_time')
    Cleaning = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CLEANING_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fl_no
```

The views.py in status app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from status.forms import StatusForm
from status.models import FlightStatus
from postlog.models import flight
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.
class StatusPageView(CreateView):

    template_name = "status/home.html"
    model = FlightStatus
    form_class = StatusForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('status') 

def load_park_bay(request):
    flight_id = request.GET.get('fl_no')
    park = flight.objects.filter(flight_id=flight_id).order_by('park_bay')
    return render(request, 'status/park_bay_dropdown.html', {'park':park})
```

The urls.py in status app:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from status.views import StatusPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.StatusPageView.as_view(), name='status'),
    path('ajax/load-park/', views.load_park_bay, name='ajax_load_park'),
]
```

home.html :

```
{% extends 'base_template1.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<button type="button" class="butra button1ra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add_Modal">Add Flight Status</button>
<!-- Adding a Flight Status -->

<div class="modal fade" id="Add_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Add_ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="AddModalLabel">Flight Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </form>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Details</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script>
    $("#id_fl_no").change(function () {
      var url = $("#StatusForm").attr("data-park-url");  
      var flnoId = $(this).val();  
      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'fl_no': flnoId       
        },
        success: function (data) {   
          $("#id_park_bay").html(data);  
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

And park_bay_dropdown.html:

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for parks in park %}
<option value="{{ parks.pk }}">{{ parks.park_bay }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, upon selecting a fl no value the other dropdowns must show only attributes related to fl no.

Suppose I had two records in my flight table. Let's say EK565 and EK545. Upon selecting EK565, I want the other drop-downs to show the values associated with EK565.

Comment: Is an underscore missing from "#id_fl no" and "#id_park bay"?

Comment: Have updated the code

Comment: Are those the ids of the fields on your form? You have to adapt the code from the tutorial to your code.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I'm not sure where I went wrong